# WordPress enqueue style with dependency causes 503 error with CDN

Tags: wordpress

I've never experienced this before but when I tried to enqueue a stylesheet from a CDN with a dependency I get a 503 error.  If I remove the dependency to 'parent-style' the page loads without an error.  Any ideas?

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_child_theme_scripts' );

function my_child_theme_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'font-awesome', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css', array('parent-style'), '4.7.0' );
}
```

Comment: Anything in the error log? Is `parent-style` registered?

Comment: The error log was showing some messages about not enough memory ie PHP: Fatal Error: Allowed Memory Size of xxxx Bytes Exhausted.  It's like the process gets caught in an infinite loop and exhausts all the memory.  I'm going to try and use a static file instead of the CDN and see if the same problems occurs.

Comment: If your memory limit isn't very high, try raising it. Lots of plugins aren't too efficient in their memory usage, and that can lead to pretty much random changes resulting in a 5XX (though I'd expected a 500, but that might be a config issue, a reverse proxy in front of your apache etc).